# Ubuntu 12.04 and Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: 12.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have just installed the "Windows" version (To try out) of Ubuntu 12.04 and everything went fine with the install, only problem is I cannot find a way of using my Bluetooth Mouse as Ubuntu keeps asking for the "key" on the device...
What key ? there is no key or number on the device, anyone know what this is all about.

When I'm using Ubuntu I have to resort to a standard USB wired mouse..

I normally use the Bluetooth mouse on both Windows 7 and Mac OSx Lion without any problems what so ever...

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a Microsoft Bluetooth mouse and the pairing key is 0000.   This is common for many devices, but check your manual.

Try 0000 or the key given in the documentation as the pairing key when asked.